# Move Specific Files From Many Folders To One Single Folder

Tags: move, robocopy

I am wondering if I can do the following with Robocopy:

I have a folder that has hundreds of folders all labeled as folder_1, folder_12, _folder_45, folder_106, folder 700, etc.

Each of them has at least 3 pdf files in them.  I know I will have to use *.pdf somewhere in my command.

I have another folder called PDFs.  This folder has NO sub-folders.

I want to MOVE all the PDF files from all the folders to the PDF folder without copying the folders.  I want all PDFs to end up in the root.  I also want to auto-rename in the case of any duplicates.  I don't expect many duplicates, but some and I don't want to lose anything.

Thank you.